# Когда транслитерировать названия соцсетей?

Tags: транслитерация

Все чаще названия наиболее популярных соцсетей транслитерируются. Например, пишут "фейсбук", "твиттер", "инстаграм" и т.д. Но что делать, когда в тексте перемежаются эти названия с другими — менее известными.

> Выкладывайте ваши посты в фейсбуке, инстаграме, Snapchat и Youtube.

Нужно ли приводить все к общему виду (транслитерировать все или не транслитерировать вовсе) или так и оставить?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так предложение смотрится очень странно. Создаётся впечатление, что у автора возникла проблема при транслитерации остальных названий и он решил остановится на полпути. Гораздо лучше привести всё к общему виду.

А если писать названия на трёх-четырёх языках... Это вообще будет выглядеть, как каша.